# Setting page numbers to appear from a set page

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

In a Word 2013 document, I want page numbers to begin to appear from page **12** onwards.

However, whevener I delete any page number such as 11, all other page numbers disappear.

**Link to Previous** is unchecked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It was a typo which has just been corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your whole document is a single section, which means it will have the same headers and footers.

At the end of page 11, add a **Next Page Section Break.** (On the **Page Layout** tab, select **Breaks** and **Next Page Section Break**.) Then, go back to your headers and footers. Make sure **Link to Previous** is unchecked in the section where you want to start numbering. (If you only had one section, this will be Section 2.) After you have that section the way you want it, go back to Section 1 and delete the page numbers.